# Save pandas dataframe to file including index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, save

Which file format can be used to save a Pandas DataFrame object and then loading it back with the proper index? I.e. if column `blah` was an index before saving it to the file, I want that after loading it back again `blah` to be an index without me having to tell this to Pandas.

Comment: `df.to_csv(..., index=True)` and `df = pd.read_csv(..., index_col=[0])`.

Comment: That only works if the index has one column, fails with multiple columns.

Comment: It's a list, specify multiple columns: `index_col=[0, 1]`. Otherwise use `pickle` as in the duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

```py
df.to_pickle('file.pickle')
df = pd.read_pickle('file.pickle')
```